# Loading sencha app 2.1 into cordova 2.3

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cordova, windows-phone-8

How to load in a sencha touch app into cordova 2.3 using windows visual studio 2012.

So I have a test sencha app that I've prepared and I can view it locally with my web server.

I have also created a Cordova WP8 full project inside Visual studio Express 2012 for phones.
This project has a www folder with the required imports etc.

When I run the cordova project it loads the app.initialize()

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

If I copy in the resources and other sencha folders including the sencha app.js file which I'm presuming loads the sencha app into the www folder (www folder inside cordova project).  How do I get the cordova framework to load the sencha app.

This is the line from the sencha index.html that loads the sencha app. Which folders would I need to copy into the www folder and in term of paths etc I'm not sure exactly where they should go.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Sencha Touch 2.2 sdk (there is alpha version available now) + according to Release Notes you will need to update your app to 2.2.

[Sencha Touch 2.2.0 alpha](http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=91&a=36)

I would recommend to wait some time until there is available detailed technical articles how to run sencha+cordova on wp8.

Comment: Thanks, is Sencha (no matter what version) just javascript at the end of the day. I understand if say version 2.1 isn't optimised for windows 8 phones but why wouldn't it run.  (I'm very much newbie to sencha/JS, so still looking for loads of answers).

Comment: Before latest release Sencha supported webkit only browsers. Webkit specific js/css won't work on WP8. So you will need to switch to 2.2 Sencha SDK to run the app on IE10/WP8. Switch means not just downloadind the latest version of sdk but also updating some app structure to be consistent with new sdk version (most likely there will be some sort of automated script for this).